# CCL Cocoa bridge "hello world" not working?

Tags: macos, cocoa, common-lisp, ccl

I'm trying to run the "hello world" script provided by Clozure for the CCL-Cocoa bridge:

https://trac.clozure.com/ccl/wiki/CocoaBridge

> Load the file containing these forms, evaluate (show-red-window), and you'll see a red window.

`red-window.ccl`

```
(in-package "CL-USER")

(require "COCOA")

(defclass red-view (ns:ns-view)
  ()
  (:metaclass ns:+ns-object))

(objc:defmethod (#/drawRect: :void) ((self red-view) (rect :<NSR>ect))
  (#/set (#/redColor ns:ns-color))
  (#_NSRectFill (#/bounds self)))

(defun show-red-window ()
  (ccl::with-autorelease-pool
   (let* ((rect (ns:make-ns-rect 0 0 300 300))
      (w (make-instance 'ns:ns-window
                :with-content-rect rect
                :style-mask (logior #$NSTitledWindowMask
                           #$NSClosableWindowMask
                           #$NSMiniaturizableWindowMask)
                :backing #$NSBackingStoreBuffered
                :defer t)))
     (#/setTitle: w #@"Red")
     (#/setContentView: w (#/autorelease (make-instance 'red-view)))
     (#/center w)
     (#/orderFront: w nil)
     (#/contentView w))))
```

But when I run `ccl64` and type

```
(load "red-window.ccl")
(show-red-window)
```

I just get this output on the terminal:

```
#<RED-VIEW <RedView: 0x4cd530> (#x4CD530)>
```

and nothing else appears to happen.

Am I missing something? I'm new to both CL and Cocoa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
(gui:execute-in-gui #'(lambda () (show-red-window)))
```

The page with the red window example was last updated 10 years ago. [One of the other examples](https://trac.clozure.com/ccl/wiki/GradientWindow) from  was [last modified](https://trac.clozure.com/ccl/wiki/GradientWindow?action=diff&version=3) 13 days ago to include `gui:execute-in-gui`.